# Landscape layout change to portrait

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, portrait

I have a giant project which was made for landscape desktop computers using Google Chrome browser.

But suddenly the requirement is it has to run now in Portrait computer (its not mobile/ipad/tablet device, but all-in-one touch screen computers). I am looking for some smart way but still could not find any.

```
<div id='i_wasdesigned_for_landscape'>
Landscape: My texts are horizontally from left to right
<button>left to right: 1</button>
<button>left to right: 2</button>
</div>
```

Now i need to fit this: `i_wasdesigned_for_landscape` into portrait screen
How can i fit it?

Comment: Google "media queries": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Screen remain landscape. But physically the orientation is rotated to look like Portrait (its complicated)

Comment: What ever we see is remaining as it is landscape, but the screen is simply rotated 90degree clockwise to make portrait effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
zoom: 0.95;
```